# Laravel dynamic route from MySQL

Tags: dynamic, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I am trying to generate routes from one template "tuning.blade.php"

I have a DB with 250 rows I would like to dynamically create 250 routes with one route or one  controller.

I want to be able to use these URLs

```
laravel.dev/tuning/(field from DB row 1)
laravel.dev/tuning/(field from DB row 2 and so on)
```

I want to put the DB requests in tuning.blade.php so that this template can display all 250 rows using 250 different URLS

I have tried to use the first example from Laravel Docs

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     */
    public function showProfile($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);

        return View::make('user.profile', array('user' => $user));
    }

}


Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@showProfile');
```

I also got some interesting search results from http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=9010
But alsas I always end up with a notfound exception

But I am unsure what to put in my tuning template to display anything at all. my Tuning template reside in app/views/home/tuning.blade.php

Currently I have got the error "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException"

Can anyone put me in the right direction of where I can find a resource to help me understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said you want to be able to use these `URL`s:

```
laravel.dev/tuning/(field from DB row 1)
laravel.dev/tuning/(field from DB row 2 and so on)
```

You can do this by declaring a route like this:

```
Route::any('/tuning/{field}', 'TuningController@someMethod'); you may get/post
```

You shouldn't run sql queries from your `view` and if you want to really declare some dynamic routes for each fields from your database then you may do id right from your `routes.php` file, for example, assume that you have a table named `tunings` and that table contains some fields including `id`, `name` and some others. Now, to declare routes individually for each routes dynamically using the `tuning` field of table `tunings` you may create a method in your `TuningController`, something like this:

```
class TuningController extends baseController {
    // other methods...

    public function registerTuningRoutes()
    {
        $tunings = Tuning::all(); // Assume that you have a model Tuning

        // Or you may use this instead
        $tunings = DB::table('tuning')->get();

        // Now loop all tunings and declare routes
        foreach($tunings as $tuning) {
            $url = '/tuning/' . $tuning->name;
            $route_name = 'tuning.' . $tuning->name;
            Route::any($url, $route_name); // You may use get/post
        }
    }

    public function TuningMethod($tuning = null)
    {
        // $tuning will contain the current tuning name, check
        dd($tuning);
    }
}
```

Now in your `routes.php` file use something like this:

```
Registers route for each tuning name in database
App::make('TuningController')->registerTuningRoutes();
```

From your terminal/command prompt check the routes by running following command:

```
php artisan routes
```

But, I think, you don't need to do this, only one route is enough as I mentioned earlier in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm not sure I understand eactly how I would use this. I have added the TuningController and emitted the Model as it threw an error. I added App::make('TuningController')->registerTuningRoutes(); to my route file but I get a not found exception in the browser. Though when I run php artisan routes I can see them all there! How would I view each route?

Comment: Try to use `url` for each routes provided in the console when you used `php artisan routes` and check thje `TuningMethod` in the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again :) I treid an url ie laravel/tuning/cgcfce and it printed `string 'cgcfce' (length=6)` though if I change cgcfce to something that is not in the database it also printed that out ie `string 'cgcfce' (length=6)` Is that right? I would ideally like to print out the contents of the row and style and change is with php and css

Comment: Sorry I meant that it will print out something that is not in the database ie string 'cgcfceX' (length=7)

Comment: Yes, anything passed to the route as a parameter when dynamically creating routes will be in the `$tuning`.

Comment: Where would I put the code to print out other fields from the database row that is associated with the `url` data?

Comment: Thanks for all of you time on this. I realise now that I execute all of my logic inside of the TuningMethod function. Thank you so much for making this clear to me.